# Why do I get different result for the this codes?

Tags: python

```
my_list = [20, 40, 60]
my_list.append(80)
my_list.remove(20)
print(my_list)
```

The result is 40, 60, 80 as it is expected

```
my_list = [20, 40, 60]
my_list.append(80)
print(my_list.remove(20))
```

The result here is None, but why?

Comment: because `my_list.remove(20)` returns `None`, and you are printing the return value of that method, not the list which was mutated, like above: `print(my_list)`